# Statement and Function not covered when testing a method that calls a http service inside component

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a component that calls a http service inside of a method.
But the Karma Coverage is showing "statement not covered" and "function not covered" on the `subscribe` method.
What I'm doing wrong? And what's the correct way to test it?

[image]

```
//post.service.ts
deletePost(id: number){
    return this.http.delete('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id);
}


//app.component.spec.ts
import { fakeAsync, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { PostService } from './services/post.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let postService: PostService;
  let mockPostService: any;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockPostService = jasmine.createSpyObj('PostService', ['deletePost'])
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: postService,
          useValue: mockPostService
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it(`should delete a post and the result must be an object {}`, fakeAsync(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;

    mockPostService.deletePost.and.returnValue(of({}));

    spyOn(app, 'deletePost').and.callThrough();
    app.deletePost(1);

    mockPostService.deletePost(1).subscribe((result: any) => {
      expect(result).toEqual({});
    });
  }));
});
```

Comment: BTW, it's generally accepted that unless you're writing tests for safety-critical systems, trying to reach the "100% code-coverage" is a waste of misdirected effort: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123777/is-100-code-coverage-a-really-good-thing-when-doing-unit-tests - so don't worry too much about small gaps in coverage.

Comment: Have you used your step-through debugger to set a breakpoint inside the `deletePost`'s `subscribe` callback to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try below in the providers section

```
{
provide: PostService,
useClass: mockPostService
}
```

and you have to create a Class at the top like below:

```
export class mockPostService{
deletePost(): Observable<any>{
    return of(<Your Mocked data>);
}
}
```

this should work